# Parsing XML of unequal number of tags to make lists of equal length. openpyxl and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, excel, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I have an XML file that have book records that contains tags like the author, publication date, labels and so on. I'm going to parse this file to make 3 lists, one will have the book title, the author in another list, and finally the labels in a third list, later I will write these lists to Excel columns using openpyxl. 
The problem is that some of the book records don't have a label tag. Using regular parsing technique with Beautiful soup will produce the first two lists with the same length, but the label list will have a shorter length.

I have three questions:

1- how do I create all three lists with equal length (empty entry for books that dont have the label tag?
2- The label list looks like this ['Energy;Green Buildings;High Performance Buildings', 'Computing', 'Computing;Design;Green Buildings',.......]. I have created about an additional 15 columns titled with the label names that I have, such as "Computing" and "Design". Is there any way that I can use openpyXL to create an X mark or colored cell for the book-label combination if a book contains a specific label, for example, if a book titled "Architecture" in row 5 has the "Design" label, I need to have either a X mark or colored cell in cell(row'5',col'Design').
3- Is there an easier method to accomplish this (parsing the XML file and writing efficiently in Excel)?

Here is a snap shot of the XML file and the code that I wrote ( also both the XML file and the Python files can be downloaded from here: http://www.ranialabib.com/#!python/icfwa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <records>
        <record>
            <database name="My Collection.enl" path="My Collection.enl">My Collection.enl</database>
            <ref-type name="Book">1</ref-type>
            <contributors>
                <authors>
                    <author>AIA Research Corporation</author>
                </authors>
            </contributors>
            <titles>
                <title>Regional guidelines for building passive energy conserving homes</title>
            </titles>
            <periodical/>
            <keywords/>
            <dates>
                <year>1978</year>
            </dates>
            <publisher>Dept. of Housing and Urban Development, Office of Policy Development and Research : for sale by the Supt. of Docs., U.S. Govt. Print. Off.</publisher>
            <urls/>
            <label>Energy;Green Buildings;High Performance Buildings</label>
        </record>
    <record>
            <database name="My Collection.enl" path="My Collection.enl">My Collection.enl</database>
            <ref-type name="Book">1</ref-type>
            <contributors>
                <authors>
                    <author>Akinci, Burcu</author>
                    <author>Ph, D</author>
                </authors>
            </contributors>
            <titles>
                <title>Computing in Civil Engineering</title>
            </titles>
            <periodical/>
            <pages>692-699</pages>
            <keywords/>
            <dates>
                <year>2007</year>
            </dates>
            <publisher>American Society of Civil Engineers</publisher>
            <isbn>9780784409374</isbn>
            <electronic-resource-num>ISBN 978-0-7844-1302-9</electronic-resource-num>
            <urls>
                <web-urls>
                    <url>http://books.google.com/books?id=QigBgc-qgdoC</url>
                </web-urls>
            </urls>
        </record>



import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fhand = open('My_Collection.xml')
data = fhand.read()

Title=list()
Year=list()
Label=list()

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
titles = tree.findall('.//title')
years = tree.findall('.//year')
labels = tree.findall('.//label')


for t in titles : 
    Title.append(str(t.text))
print 'Titles: ', len(Title)
print Title

for y in years : 
    Year.append(str(y.text))
print 'years: ', len(Year)
print Year

for l in labels : 
    Label.append(str(l.text))
print 'Labels: ', len(Label)
print Label

from openpyxl import Workbook 
wb = Workbook() 
ws = wb.active 

for row in zip(Title, Year, Label): 
        ws.append(row) 

wb.save("Test2.xlsx")
```

Here is a code that I wrote based on Charlie's suggestion, the code didn't work. I got an error message saying"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".I'm not sure what the problem is.
Also how do I get the text of all 3 tags( Title, Year, Label) of each record in one list, and how easy is to write such a large number of lists (200 list for 200 books) to Excel using openpylx?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fhand = open('My_Collection.xml')
data = fhand.read()
Label_lst=list()
for record in tree.find("records/record") :
    label = record.find("label")

for l in label:    
        if label is not None: label = label_lst.append(label.text)
    else:
        label = label_lst.append(' ') 
print label_lst
```

Comment: Why use Python? Excel VBA has the [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195815%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method to import xml into workbook: `Workbooks.OpenXML "C:\Path\To\XMLfile.xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList`

Comment: @Parfait who says Excel itself is actually available on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I still used columns though.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



fhand = open ('My_Collection')    
tree =ET.parse('My_Collection.xml')
data= fhand.read()
root = tree.getroot()
tree = ET.fromstring(data)

title_list= ['Title']
year_list = ['Year']
author_list= ['Author']
label_list = ['Label']



for child in tree:
    for children in child:
        if children.find('.//title')is None :
            t='N'
        else:
            t=children.find('.//title').text
        title_list.append(t)
    print title_list
    print len(title_list)


for child in tree:
    for children in child:
        if children.find('.//year')is None :
            y='N'
        else:
            y=children.find('.//year').text
        year_list.append(y)
    print year_list
    print len(year_list)


for child in tree:
    for children in child:
        if children.find('.//author')is None :
            a='N'
        else:
            a=children.find('.//author').text
        author_list.append(a)
    print author_list
    print len(author_list)

for child in tree:
    for children in child:
        if children.find('label')is None :
            l='N'
        else:
            l=children.find('label').text
        label_list.append(l)
    print label_list
print len(author_list) 

for item in label_list:





wb = Workbook() 
ws = wb.active 

for row in zip(title_list, year_list, author_list, label_list): 
        ws.append(row) 

wb.save("Test3.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the record structure you should parse record-by-record rather just creating lists of the attributes. You can loop through the records and extract the relevant fields or `for record in parsed_xml.find("records/record"); label = record.find("label"); if label is not None: label = label.text` You can then write the rows straight to Excel without having to zip over the columns.

Comment: Charlie, This is a great idea, I don't know why I wasn't thinking about keeping the record structure same and writing to Excel in Rows. I wrote a code based on your suggestion that I'll post above. The code didn't work, I get an error saying " TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Well, I can see how seductive the the shortcuts for processing XML are.

Comment: You should extend the code I suggested to extract the title, year and label for each record in to a list which can then be fed to openpyxl as a row. This means doing without the intermediate lists altogether. 200 is not a large number of items. If you have several million then you can just switch to using `iterparse` and openpyxl's `write_only` mode.